# How to setup a associative data structure in Arduino

Tags: arrays, struct, arduino, associative-array

I'm just developing a small remote control which lets me control my [IR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared) controlled devices via the Internet. All is working, but I still need to store the codes in a way that I can easily access them. So I would like to have a way in which I can have two variables:

- A 'char rc_name[]' which holds the name of the remote control, for example, TV, SAT, and AMPLIFIER
- A 'char rc_function[]' which holds the name of the function to execute, for example, POWER, VOLUME_UP, and BUTTON_1

Given these two variables I then want to receive all the necessary data.

- 'int code_type_num'
- 'char code_value[]', for example, "400555AA"
- 'int code_type_bits

This all seems simple in general, but I could not really find a way which would let me access the data by the string key rather than an integer inex.

In PHP I would use something like this:

```
$remotes = array(
    'tv' => array(
                    'POWER' => array(1, '400555AA', 32),
                    'MUTE'   => array(1, '400557AA', 32),
            ),
);

$rc_name = 'tv';
$rc_function = 'power';
$rc_data = $remotes[$rc_name][$rc_function];
```

What would be the best way to setup such a structure in Arduino?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then a hashmap might be a good solution. http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/HashMap

Answer (score 3):

My current approach is also to iterate through it. I was hoping there is a more elegant way.
In case someone else needs it, here is how I do it for now:

```
typedef struct {
   char* remote_name;
   char* function_name;
   int code_type;
   int code_bits;
   char* code_value;
} IR_Code;

int num_codes = 58;
IR_Code ir_codes[58] = {
   { "amp", "power", 1, 32, "400501FE" }, 
   ...
   { "tv", "power", 1, 32, "20DF10EF" },
};

void send_defined_code(char* remote_name, char* function_name) {
  for( int i=0; i < num_codes; i++) {
     if(strcmp(remote_name, ir_codes[i].remote_name) == 0 && strcmp(function_name, ir_codes[i].function_name) == 0) {
       long unsigned int code = strtoul( ir_codes[i].code_value, 0, 16);
       Serial.print(F(" Type:"));
       Serial.print(ir_codes[i].code_type);
       Serial.print(F(" Value:0x"));
       Serial.print(code, HEX);
       Serial.print(F(" Bits:"));
       Serial.print(ir_codes[i].code_bits);
       return;
     }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me with a similar problem. It's true, there should be a more elegatn way of doing this.